# Unable to Upload artifacts under "build" folder for Spring boot service build jar file using CICD pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the below gitlab.yml file in my spring boot service, after i made some changes and now i could see it is building jar file in Gitlab but it is Unable to Upload artifacts under "build" folder. Mine is a Spring boot intellij based Gradle project.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  image: gradle:jdk17
  services:
      - docker:dind # use the docker-in-docker image
  before_script: # install docker
      - apt update && apt install --no-install-recommends -y docker.io
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew clean build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/libs/

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - sleep 60
    - echo "Code coverage is 90%"

lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "No lint issues found."

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

I got below pipeline output:

```
$ echo "Compiling the code..."
Compiling the code...
$ echo "Compile complete."
Compile complete.
$ chmod +x ./gradlew
$ ./gradlew clean build
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
...........10%............20%...........30%............40%............50%...........60%............70%............80%...........90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.6.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Added support for Java 19.
 - Introduced `--rerun` flag for individual task rerun.
 - Improved dependency block for test suites to be strongly typed.
 - Added a pluggable system for Java toolchains provisioning.
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava
Note: /builds/test1555/awstest/src/main/java/com/example/awstest/repository/MMTServiceDAO.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /builds/test1555/awstest/src/main/java/com/example/awstest/handler/AWSLambdaHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :resolveMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
> Task :check
> Task :build
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 39s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:07
Uploading artifacts...
./build/libs/: found 3 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/4619641405/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=4619641405 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_rxRWT
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Could you please tell me, how to make jar file Uploading under "Build" artifacts folder?

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the build log, uploading succeeds: `Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=4619641405 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_rxRWT`. What exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: Also, the `Job artifacts` section on the right in your last screenshot shows that it has successfully uploaded some artifacts.

Comment: new jar should be updated in "Build" folder , correct?

Comment: No. Build artifacts do not go into the repository, build artifacts can be downloaded from the jobs page that is seen in your last screenshot, using "Download" or "Browse" links on the right.

Comment: Oh Ok. I need to further push this jar to Docker and deploy to lambda from there. That's the next step, i need to do. So, i was having doubt, where was build created.

Comment: FYI artifacts are also available to subsequent jobs on the same pipeline, so you are on the right path.